# "Launch Images" of the "Summary" for localized Default.png

Tags: ios, xcode

In my Xcode project I have got localized Default.png images:

[image]

It works fine, but I faced problem: what files I need select for the properties "Summary" - "Launch Images"?

[image]

Comment: remove all these images and add it once again all images automatically added.